# ssh-add in script has no effect on user - have to redo ssh-add

Tags: ssh

I am running ssh-add in a setup script:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/<some_key>
```

Problem is that I have to redo `ssh-add` for each key when logging in for the first time.

In the same script I setup `ssh-agent.service` before `ssh-add`

Service:

```
sudo cat << EOF > /etc/systemd/user/ssh-agent.service
[Unit]
Description=SSH authentication agent

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh-agent -a %t/ssh-agent.socket -D
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
EOF

    systemctl --user enable ssh-agent.service
    systemctl --user start ssh-agent.service

    echo export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/ssh-agent.socket" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Do you know how to `ssh-add` so I dont have to redo each key the first time I login?

Comment: The behaviour of ssh-add changed recently on a 20.04 machine for me as well.